# Having a script used only on one specific page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on an app with jQuery mobile. I have a script that I want to start once the user enters a page and stops once they leave.

I have used:

```
$( document ).delegate("#myPage", "pagecreate", "", function() {
    //my script here
});
```

to have the script only run once the user enters "myPage." How can I have it so the script stops once they leave "myPage"?

Edit: I am using ajax-based navigation so it is all one HTML file. I am trying to start and stop a script when someone enters a new subpage (#page).

Comment: What is your script doing that it needs to run the entire time the page is loaded? There may be a better approach.

Comment: We need to know what the script is doing. Basically, you need to stop it manually. If we don't know what it is doing, we can't help you stop it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pageshow` and `pagehide` events for a specific pseudo-page. Something like this:

```
$( document ).delegate("#myPage", "pageshow", function() {
    //start your code
}).delegate("#myPage", "pagehide", function() {
    //end your code
});
```

Here is the documentation for jQuery Mobile Events, there is a whole section on page-events: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html

Using `pageshow`/`pagehide` has the advantage that the code will run on subsequent views of the pseudo-page as well, not just on the first page-load.